# Java nested list to array conversion

Tags: java, arrays, list, jtable

What is the most efficient way to convert data from nested lists to an object array (which can be used i.e. as data for JTable)?

```
List<List> table = new ArrayList<List>();

for (DATAROW rowData : entries) {
    List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String col : rowData.getDataColumn())
        row.add(col);

    table.add(row);
}

// I'm doing the conversion manually now, but
// I hope that there are better ways to achieve the same
Object[][] finalData = new String[table.size()][max];
for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
    List<String> row = table.get(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++)
        finalData[i][j] = row.get(j);
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
//defined somewhere
List<List<String>> lists = ....

String[][] array = new String[lists.size()][];
String[] blankArray = new String[0];
for(int i=0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    array[i] = lists.get(i).toArray(blankArray);
}
```

I don't know anything about JTable, but converting a list of lists to array can be done with a few lines.

Answer (score 8):

For `JTable` in particular, I'd suggest subclassing `AbstractTableModel` like so:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private List<List<String>> data;
    public MyTableModel(List<List<String>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return data.get(0).size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return data.get(row).get(column);
    }
    // optional
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
        data.get(row).set(column, aValue);
    }
}
```

Note: this is the most basic implementation possible; error-checking is omitted for brevity.

Using a model like this, you don't have to worry about pointless conversions to `Object[][]`.

Comment: Good answer.  However, double-check that the data passed to this model isn't visible elsewhere, and prone to ninja-editing.  It probably isn't, but if it is, it may need to be cloned here.

Comment: Good point. I thought of that, but DefaultTableModel actually doesn't check either (it uses Vectors). Anyway, this is the most basic implementation possible. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Java 11 answer.

```
List<List<String>> table = List.of(List.of("A", "B"), List.of("3", "4"));
String[][] finalData = table.stream()
        .map(arr -> arr.toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
    
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(finalData));
```

> [[A, B], [3, 4]]

The `Collection.toArray​(IntFunction<T[]> generator)` method is new in Java 11.

Of course you may also use a stream in Java 8+. Just use this mapping instead:

```
.map(arr -> arr.toArray(new String[0]))
```

(The `List.of` method was introduced in Java 9.)

Answer (score 0):

To convert a nested list to a two-dimensional object-array, you can use this code:

```
public Object[][] ToObjectMatrix(List<List<String>> data) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if(data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Passed data was null.");
    }

    Object[][] result = new Object[data.size()][];
     
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = data.get(i).toArray();
    }
     
    return result;
}
```